# How can I Add ADS Route in Twincat programmatically

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

How can I add ads route programmatically?

I can add route only by TcAmsRemoteMgr.exe. The code that I only can find is https://github.com/nikvoronin/AdsRemote.

But, it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Please share with us the output `TcAmsRemoteMgr.exe`

Comment: You can add ads routes with the automation interface api.
https://infosys.beckhoff.de/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_automationinterface/36028797261903755.html&id=

Answer (score 0):

You can add routes from within the PLC user code too. See [this link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/9007199289714315.html&id=8061927282160270342). Please mark this as the answer if you think it is correct.